# How to change all url with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, url, browser, browser-history

When I change my URL with history.pushState(newUrl) a few times and after that I try to go back for one page I have an error, I found out that if I do pushState(newUrl/) instead of (newUrl), this error disappears, but now pushState does not replace the URL but adds it by type
The first time I called pushState on "mySite.com" I get "mySite.com/newUrl/"
Second time I call pushState on "mySite.com" I get "mySite.com/newUrl/newUrl/"

Method history.replaceState gave the same result

So here is the question How can I always replace the URL without reloading the page and always get "mySite.com/newUrl/"

Well I googled it and found nothing, help me Please

Comment: So you just found out how relative URLs work then ... Use a root-relative URL, beginning with a leading slash, to avoid the path being combined with the current path that you are "on".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an absolute URL that you feed into `pushState()` *or* add a leading slash to the relative URL.

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) docs:

> The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL.